# CollectionView has a slight offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have 2 collectionViews nested in a navigationController, but both my collectionViews have a little offset at the top of the frame (see screenshot).

[image: White offset above my blue background.]

I also get the following error message: (not crashing)

> the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.

How can I set the frame correctly? 
I tried to set the frame of the collectionView manually, but it does not work:

```
collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 
                                  self.view.frame.origin.y, 
                                  self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                  self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me since I figured, that if I use 2 collectionViews in a navigationViewController there is a 10px offset for the top bar:

```
myollectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your viewController set:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```